# Create executable jar file for Cucumber Selenium project

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, bdd

**Problem**: I want to create an executable jar of my BDD Cucumber Selenium framework, which I can run using command like "java -jar bddframework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to directly create a jar file by "mvn clean package". I did get an jar file but when I run it using java -jar ***, I get below message:

   *no main manifest attribute, in bddframework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*
2. Then I tried adding a main method as below by adding a new Main.java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String[] arguments = {"--plugin", "html:build/reports/cucumber", "--glue", "com.demo.amazonbdddocker.teststeps", "src/test/resources/feature"};
        cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);
    }
```

Still I get the same error: no main manifest attribute

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i agree. will refrain in future. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of that issue is you are just creating a jar file NOT EXECUTABLE JAR. In order to create the executable jar, you need to do the below configuration in the POM.xml and after that you will be able to create the executable jar file.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and then you can run the below maven goals

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```